# Web view content is missing

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

Here is a start button showing in the first image but sometimes that start button is missing

[image]

The start button is missing sometimes
anybody help me to solve this problem in Android?
Thanks!

Comment: Please open the URL in your mobile browser, not in the computer and check that the content is showing or not

Comment: You not provide any information.  Image is not enough

Comment: Never post a screenshot of code.
Please edit your question and copy/past the interesting part related to your issue inside a code block.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your components for UI like bootstrap , element-ui or what ever you use , are downloaded and located to your right directory instead of using them directly from the link that they provide for fast use ,often connection problems cause css/js files to be missing and causing that problem.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please explain your answer more, add examples and code snippets